# Pandas numpy compare two array of different size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 arrays, one of 1000 values and the other one of 8448 values.
I'm tryig to count the number of identique values in the two dataframe.

```
t1 = dfRight['X'].values
t2 = dfLeft['X'].values
t1 == t2
```

But it return "False", someone know an easy ways to do this please ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
np.intersect1d(t1, t2)
```

or using Pandas:

```
dfRight.merge(dfLeft, on='X')
```

Data:

```
In [79]: dfRight
Out[79]:
   X
0  1
1  3
2  5
3  7

In [80]: dfLeft
Out[80]:
   X
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
7  8
8  9
```

Merging:

```
In [82]: dfRight.merge(dfLeft, on='X')
Out[82]:
   X
0  1
1  3
2  5
3  7
```

Counting:

```
In [81]: dfRight['X'].isin(dfLeft['X']).sum()
Out[81]: 4
```